Obtener el último registro de una tabla SQL Server
tengo una tabla en la base de datos denominada Pacientes, el caso es que, por cada vez que inserto un nuevo registro, desearía obtener el ID del paciente, aunque ya tengo creado mi procedimiento de almacenado de insertar pacientes:
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREA_PACIENTE
 @cedula varchar(10),
 @nombres varchar(50),
 @apellidos varchar(50),
 @correo varchar(50),
 @telefono varchar(50),
 @direccion varchar(50)
AS
 INSERT INTO Paciente (Cedula_Paciente,Nombres_Paciente,Apellidos_Paciente,
               Correo_Paciente,Telefono_Paciente,Direccion_Paciente)
 VALUES(@cedula,@nombres,@apellidos,@correo,@telefono,@direccion);
EN
GO

Estos son los registros que tengo en mi base de datos de prueba:

Ahora, me gustaría de alguna manera obtener dicho ID con un procedimiento de almacenado que me permita, como que si fuera una consulta, pero creo que la idea no es así.
De qué manera obtendría el ID del ultimo registro de dicha tabla (ID_Paciente) y tenerlo almacenado en un procedimiento almacenado.
El ID es incremental, por cada vez que se inserta un nuevo registro se incrementa el ID.
Este es un ejemplo de tipo consulta que quiero ejecutar luego de obtener el ID del paciente, luego de la última inserción, si se puede decir así:
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_OBTENER_PACIENTE
 @ID_Paciente int
AS
select ID_Paciente,Cedula,
       Nombres_Medico +' '+ Apellidos_Medico AS Nombres_Apellidos,
       Correo_Paciente, Telefono, Direccion
from Paciente where ID_Paciente = @ID_Paciente,;
GO

Así muestro los datos del ultimo paciente en un formulario de Windows Forms, en donde los visualizare en un TextBox

Este es un ejemplo nomas, pero la idea viene ser que, una vez de la inserción en el Formulario Agregar Paciente, en el Formulario Agendar Cita me muestre ya de una los datos del Paciente que agregué recientemente, que en este caso seria el ultimo agregado o insertado en la base de datos. Yo antes probe haciendo una consulta en donde pasaba el numero de cédula y por medio del select con where ejecuté y me mostró los datos de dicha fila, pero ahora viene a ser el último paciente que agregue al formulario.

Creo que lo que buscas es el ID recién insertado verdad?? Que lenguaje estas usando para todo lo demás? Porque por ejemplo en PHP es fácil lo que quieres con lastInsertId()

Bueno lo estoy ejecutando con C#

Por favor, en el futuro no utilices el espacio reservado para respuestas para publicar más datos sobre las preguntas. En StackOverflow puedes [edit] la pregunta para refinarla y agregar más información hasta que quede completa. He agregado a esta pregunta lo que habías publicado en una respuesta, que podrías borrar tú, o la moderación comunitaria terminará borrando de todas formas.

Hola podrías intentar esto:
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ULTIMO_PACIENTE
 @ID_Paciente int

AS

select top 1 ID_Paciente,Cedula,
       Nombres_Medico +' '+ Apellidos_Medico AS Nombres_Apellidos,
       Correo_Paciente, Telefono, Direccion
from Paciente
ORDER BY ID_Paciente desc;
GO

La otra alternativa seria asi:
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREA_PACIENTE
 @cedula varchar(10),
 @nombres varchar(50),
 @apellidos varchar(50),
 @correo varchar(50),
 @telefono varchar(50),
 @direccion varchar(50)
AS

 INSERT INTO Paciente (Cedula_Paciente,Nombres_Paciente,Apellidos_Paciente,
               Correo_Paciente,Telefono_Paciente,Direccion_Paciente)
 VALUES(@cedula,@nombres,@apellidos,@correo,@telefono,@direccion);

select ID_Paciente,Cedula,
       Nombres_Medico +' '+ Apellidos_Medico AS Nombres_Apellidos,
       Correo_Paciente, Telefono, Direccion
from Paciente
WHERE Cedula_Paciente = @cedula;

END

GO


Jose, siempre es bueno agregar una breve explicación del código que has escrito, para que sea de utilidad para el usuario que pregunta, como para otros que necesiten una ayuda similar en el futuro.

En un sistema con concurrencia, esto tiene el potencial de devolver el paciente insertado en otra sesión y no en la sesión actial.

Tu primera opción ignora el parámetro enviado y puede regresar datos erroneos. La otra opción depende de que haya una restricción de llave única (UNIQUE CONSTRAINT) en la columna cédula. De otro modo, también puede regresar datos incorrectos.

La manera correcta de obtener el valor asignado al ID en una nueva fila insertada en una tabla con el campo ID auto incremental es mediante el uso de la función scope_identity(), cuya documentación dice:

Devuelve el último valor de identidad insertado en una columna de identidad en el mismo ámbito. Un ámbito es un módulo: un procedimiento almacenado, desencadenador, función o lote. Por tanto, si dos instrucciones se encuentran en el mismo procedimiento almacenado, función o lote, están en el mismo ámbito.

Yo lo diría de esta forma:

Devuelve el último valor identity insertado en una columna de id en el mismo ámbito. Un ámbito es un módulo: un procedimiento almacenado, trigger, función o proceso por lotes. Por tanto, si dos instrucciones se encuentran en el mismo procedimiento almacenado, función o proceso por lotes, están en el mismo ámbito.

Mi recomendación es hacerlo de esta manera para obtener el último registro insertado en la misma sesión, que es el que espera ver el usuario final en el formulario de citas y al que se espera que quede asociada esta última. Si solo obtienes el último registro de la tabla, en un sistema con concurrencia (dónde varios usuarios insertan registros al mismo tiempo), el sistema podría potencialmente mostrar el registro insertado en otra sesión, lo cual sería un grave error.
Es importante que leas las notas de la documentación, pues aclaran el uso y las diferencias con otras formas de obtener el valor del campo identity, como @@identity e ident_current(). 1
Es importante llamar a la función dentro del mismo ámbito, por lo que tendría que ser dentro del mismo procedimiento almacenado.  Para hacer disponible el valor al lugar desde donde lo llamas, puedes valerte de un parámetro de salida, por ejemplo:
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREA_PACIENTE
 @cedula varchar(10),
 @nombres varchar(50),
 @apellidos varchar(50),
 @correo varchar(50),
 @telefono varchar(50),
 @direccion varchar(50),
 @NuevoID int output
AS
 INSERT INTO Paciente (Cedula_Paciente,Nombres_Paciente,Apellidos_Paciente,
               Correo_Paciente,Telefono_Paciente,Direccion_Paciente)
 VALUES(@cedula,@nombres,@apellidos,@correo,@telefono,@direccion);
 set @NuevoID = scope_identity();
GO

Luego, el valor obtenido en este parámetro de salida lo puedes pasar a la sentencia select o al procedimiento almacenado SP_OBTENER_PACIENTE.
Si definitivamente no puedes agregar el parámetro de salida, la siguiente mejor alternativa sería usar @@identity en cualquier otro ámbito dentro de la misma sesión, por ejemplo puedes crear un nuevo procedimiento almacenado que devuelva el último paciente:
create procedure sp_obtener_nuevo_paciente_sesion
as
  declare @id int = @@identity;
  execute SP_OBTENER_PACIENTE @id;
go

En este último, obtengo el ID del último identity de la sesión y llamo al procedimiento almacenado para obtener el paciente con ese ID (por el principio DRY). La debilidad de este enfoque es que, si se agrega algún registro a otra tabla que tiene un campo identity dentro de la cadena de acciones desencadenada por el insert a la tabla de pacientes, no voy a obtener el ID de esta tabla, sino el de la última tabla a la que se insertó un registro en dicha cadena. (Por eso es preferible el uso de la función scope_identity() mencionada al inicio de esta respuesta.

1: Los enlaces son a la documentación en inglés, pues la traducción al español de Microsoft es terrible. Si no lees inglés, puedes cambiar el idioma dentro de la página de la documentación, o usar un traductor.

Este es un ejemplo de tipo consulta que quiero ejecutar luego de obtener el ID del paciente luego de la ultima insercion si se puede decir asi:
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_OBTENER_PACIENTE
 @ID_Paciente int
AS
select ID_Paciente,Cedula,
       Nombres_Medico +' '+ Apellidos_Medico AS Nombres_Apellidos,
       Correo_Paciente, Telefono, Direccion
from Paciente where ID_Paciente = @ID_Paciente,;
GO

Asi muestro los datos del ultimo paciente en un formulario de Windows Forms en donde los visualizare en un TextBox

Este es un ejemplo nomas, pero la idea viene ser que una vez de la insercion en el Formulario Agregar Paciente en el Formulario Agendar Cita me muestre ya de una los datos del Paciente que agrege recientemente que en este caso seria el ultimo agregado o insertado en la base de datos. Yo antes probe haciendo ua consulta en donde pasaba el numero de Cedula y por medio del Select con Where ejecute y me mostro los datos de dicha fila pero ahora viene  a ser el ultimo Paciente que agrege al Formulario.
